# What is the difference between iterator with reference symbol, and without. (C++ loop)

Tags: c++, iterator, auto

What is the difference between an iterator with the & symbol, and one without it, as seen in cases 1 and 2 in the contrived example below?

When should I use one or the other?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);

    // case 1:
    for (auto & i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }

    // case 2:
    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is it something to do with the creation of an iterator object, and what is then available in the code block? I'm very new to iterators.

Comment: In this particular case ... maybe nothing :) You bind a temporary object to a reference.

Comment: @knivil Only a const reference.

Comment: @knivil what cases would show a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the "for each" ... deleted my comment.

Comment: @windenergy If you switch on the strict mode in MSVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the first loop will not be compiled.:)

```
for (auto & i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
}
```

You created a temporary object returned by member function `begin` and binded it with non-const reference.

Comment: Compiles with Intel on windows for me.

Comment: @windenergy: Indeed, that compiler accepts all sorts of dodgy code, including this. It won't compile with a more standard compiler though.

Comment: @windenergy In fact each compiler has its own bugs that creaturers of compilers sometimes call them compiler features because they are unable to fix the bugs.:)

Comment: @sometimes You should check compiler options. Maybe there is an option that force the compiler to be more C++ compliant

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks, /Wall introduces a warning about that line.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to iterators, but to how the `auto` keyword works.

This syntax

```
auto const &i = (something)
```

will create a reference to the object on the right side of the assignment; in this case, a const reference to a temporary object, which would be equivalent to

```
std::vector<int>::iterator const &i = (something)
```

Note that in this case, `auto &i = v.begin()` is invalid, since `std::vector::begin()` does not actually return a reference.

One the other hand, the syntax without reference

```
auto i = (something)
```

Will create an instance of the object, which would be equivalent to

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i = (something)
```

In practice, the two statements are equivalent since the reference is actually a lifetime expansion of the referenced object. If the function `begin()` returned a reference, the no-reference syntax would create a copy.

Comment: They are not equivalent because using a const reference prevents you from incrementing the iterator.

Comment: Yes, I overlooked that. Of course a const reference to an iterator would be almost useless.

Comment: For MSVC it is allowed to bind a temporary to a reference. It is an compiler extension. MSVC will warn about it with a higher warning level.

Comment: @knivil: Yes, but it's a nonstandard extension that fires warnings.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the second instead of the first because the first does not compile. `begin` returns a temporary object by value and it is not permitted to bind a temporary object to a non-const reference. If it does, then this is some extension provided by your compiler.

http://ideone.com/oBvFOu3

`error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}’`

Comment: Compiles with Intel on windows for me.

Comment: @windenergy `If it does, then this is some extension provided by your compiler.`